# How to change the mapping of a texture in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, interface

Using blender 2.71, I'm trying to put a texture on an object.

Following this tutorial, at 1:10 you should be able to setup a mapping

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gRUUeFteQg&t=1m10s
<sub>screen shot of tutorial with mapping pane</sub>
[image: screen shot of tutorial with mapping pane]

I'm running the same version of blender as the tutorial, yet I don't have the mapping pane in the bottom right corner. How do I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tutorial is using the *blender internal* render, you are using *cycles*.

To change the mapping type in cycles, click on the field for the *Vector* of your texture.
[image]
Or in the node editor, add either a *UV Map* node or a *Texture Coordinate* node.
[image: nodes]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Cylces you change the render engines with this menu:
[image]